# VSCode How can apply different tab size in one file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am using tab size 4 in typescript, and tab size 2 in html.

Like lit-element, react and vue, There are using html code in typescript file.

But I would like to use different tab size 4 in typescript and 2 in html code of a file. like below.

```
(()=>{
    const html = html`
    <div> <span> Depth 1</span>
      <div> <span> Depth 2</span>
        <div> <span> Depth 3</span>
          <div> <span> Depth 4</span>
                ...
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    `;
})();
```

There are way to apply different tab size in a same file?

Comment: Is this really about tab size (the indentation created by a single tab character) or rather indentation in general (i.e. how many spaces make up a single indentation step)? These are two different things.

Comment: I think that doesn't matter. but exactly, indentation.